# Query a MongoDB collection by the property of an embedded relation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find documents in a collection, but filtered based on the value of an embedded ObjectID relation.

Mongoose schema is as follows:

```js
const UserQualificationSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },
    }
```

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        fleet: {
            type: [String], // Eg ["FleetA", "FleetB", "FleetC"]
            required: true,
        }
    }
```

I need to find all UserQualifications where an item in the user's fleet equals a value in a filter array.

For example:  Find all User Qualifications where `user.fleet: {$in: ["FleetA", "FleetC"]}`

I've looked at aggregations and querying inside `.populate()` but can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: you want both FleetA & FleetC to be in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation query for your problem, I have created a query for you.

users.collection.json

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61056c4a8cca27df3db2e4c8"),
    "firstName" : "Rahul",
    "lastName" : "soni",
    "fleet" : [ 
        "FleetA", 
        "FleetB", 
        "FleetC"
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:29:14.918Z")
}
```

userqualifications.collection.json

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61056c908cca27df3db2e4c9"),
    "user" : ObjectId("61056c4a8cca27df3db2e4c8"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:30:24.510Z")
}
```

aggregation query:
it will get the result only if a user has **FleetA** and **FleetC**.
if anyone is not matched then it will return 0 records

```
db.userqualifications.aggregate([{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "user",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "user"
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$user"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "user.fleet": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$eq": "FleetA",
        "$eq": "FleetC"
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61056c908cca27df3db2e4c9"),
    "user" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61056c4a8cca27df3db2e4c8"),
        "firstName" : "Rahul",
        "lastName" : "soni",
        "fleet" : [ 
            "FleetA", 
            "FleetB", 
            "FleetC"
        ],
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:29:14.918Z")
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:30:24.510Z")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Khan Usama - this worked.  I've posted an update below as I'm struggling with a $match function.  Do you have any advice for this?

Answer (score 0):

if the goal is to get only `UserQualifications` then the following should be an efficient way as it can use an index on the `fleet` field of the `User` collection.

```
db.User.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            fleet: { $in: ["FleetA", "FleetB"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
               from: "UserQualification",
               localField: "_id",
               foreignField: "user",
               as: "qualifications"
             }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$qualifications"
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: "$qualifications"
    }
])
```

on the other hand if you start from the `UserQualifications` collection, you can't efficiently narrow down the records as you're filtering on something that it doesn't have the data for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer - it did achieve the results I was looking for - however I am now struggling to add a `$match` with `$and` to the aggregate to only return the qualifications where the user ID equals one inside a submitted array AND a given fleet.

I have the following aggregate:

```js
db.UserQualifications.aggregate([{
{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'user',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'user',
    },
},
{
  $unwind: '$user',
},
{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      'user.fleet': {
         $in: ["Fleet A", "Fleet C"],  // This works on it's own
       },
      user: { // Also tried 'user._id'
         $in: ["6033e4129070031c07fbbf29"] // Adding this returns blank array
      }
    ]
  },
}
}])
```

I have double checked that I am passing in the correct User ID's inside the arrays, but when I add this to the `$and` inside match, it only returns a blank array.
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Updated users collection

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61056c4a8cca27df3db2e4c8"),
    "firstName" : "Rahul",
    "lastName" : "soni",
    "fleet" : [ 
        "Fleet A", 
        "Fleet B", 
        "Fleet C"
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:29:14.918Z")
}
```

Query:

```
// userqualifications => this is my collection name, you can add your collection name here db.<YOUR>
db.userqualifications.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'user',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'user',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$user',
  },
  {
    $match: {
      // $and operatory syntax [{}, {}]
      $and: [{
        'user.fleet': {
          // "Fleet A", "Fleet C" (FleetA, FleetC) this is the my first options, 
          // I have changes according to your problem
          $in: ["Fleet A", "Fleet C"], // This works on it's own
        }
      }, {
        // Convert user id to ObjectId type (_bsonType) 
        "user._id": ObjectId("61056c4a8cca27df3db2e4c8")
      }]
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61056c908cca27df3db2e4c9"),
    "user" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61056c4a8cca27df3db2e4c8"),
        "firstName" : "Rahul",
        "lastName" : "soni",
        "fleet" : [ 
            "Fleet A", 
            "Fleet B", 
            "Fleet C"
        ],
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:29:14.918Z")
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-07-31T15:30:24.510Z")
}
```

Difference Image:
[image]